# @Audited table and byte[] @Lob field problem

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

I have adudited table with `@Lob` field. Without `@Audited` saving object by Spring `CrudRepository` works ok, but when i want audit turn on i get error: `PSQLException: ERROR: column "content" is of type oid but expression is of type bytea`. How to resolve this ? Content column in PostgreSQL database is `oid` type (for both tables). On Hibernate 5.x the same configuration works, but not o Hibernate 6.x.

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "up_test")
@Getter @Setter
public class UploadTestEntity extends BaseEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "up_test_seq")
    @TableGenerator(table = "id_generator", name = "up_test_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)    
    private Integer id; 
    
    @Lob
    private byte[] content;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `@Lob` annotation.

The Postgres JDBC driver does not support handling the `bytea` type via the JDBC LOB APIs `setBlob()`/`getBlob()`. I don't know why, and it seems like something that *should* be supported.

But on the other hand, you don't need it here. The most natural way to handle a field of type `byte[]` mapping to `bytea` is to use `setBytes()`/`getBytes()`, which is the job of Hibernate's `VarbinaryJdbcType`.

I don't know where people got the idea that they needed to use `@Lob` for this instead of just going with the default mapping for `byte[]`.